# DataBricks: Fastest Way to Insert Data Into Delta Table?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

I have a handful of tables that are only a few MBs in filesize each that I want to capture as Delta Tables. Inserting new data into them takes an extraordinarily long time, 15+ minutes, which I am astonished at.

The culprit, I am guessing, is that while the table is very small; there are over 300 columns in these tables.

I have tried the following methods, with the former being faster than the latter (unsurprisingly(?)): (1) `INSERT INTO` , (2) `MERGE INTO`.

Before inserting data into the Delta Tables, I apply a handful of Spark functions to clean the data and then lastly register it as a temp table (e.g., `INSERT INTO DELTA_TBL_OF_INTEREST (cols) SELECT * FROM tempTable`

Any recommendations on speeding this process up for trivial data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're performing data transformations using PySpark before putting the data into the destination table, then you don't need to go to the SQL level, you can just write data using `append` mode.

If you're using registered table:

```py
df = ... transform source data ...
df.write.mode("append").format("delta").saveAsTable("table_name")
```

If you're using file path:

```py
df = ... transform source data ...
df.write.mode("append").format("delta").save("path_to_delta")
```